# Mudar valor de uma label dinamicamente

Tags: python, tkinter

Sou iniciante em Python. Como faço para mudar o valor de uma label dinamicamente?

Para ser mais especifico, tenho o seguinte código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import socket, webbrowser

root = Tk()
root.title("Test - waghcwb")

def window(w=300, h=200):
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
window(270, 100)

def Open():
    text_contents = text.get()
    url = str(socket.gethostbyname( text.get() ))

    if url != '0.0.0.0':
        webbrowser.open("http://%s" %url)
    else:
        #Erro para a label aqui
        print("Erro")

info = Label(root, text="Testando", pady=20).pack()

text = Entry(root, width=40).pack()

button = Button(root, text="Enviar", command=Open, width=40).pack()

error = Label(root, text="", pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Notem o `else:` ali, é ali que gostaria de inserir minha mensagem de erro.

A minha ideia foi deixar uma label vazia ali e só inserir dados quando houver o erro, mas como falei sou bem iniciante e desconheço alguma maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: É isso que você quer? `error.set("novo texto")` [(fonte)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm). Nota: não tenho experiência alguma com tkinter, então não sei se entendi bem sua dúvida.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, infelizmente não deu certo amigo, ele retorna o seguinte erro: http://pastebin.com/KygvCB72
A propósito, eu cometi um equivoco com relação a versão do meu Python, a instalada aqui é a 2.7

Comment: Como eu falei, eu não entendo de tkinter, mas seu erro sugere que o método `pack` não retorna nada. Já tentou fazer em duas linhas? `text = Entry(root, width=40)` e embaixo `text.pack()`. Se isso estiver correto, é preciso fazer o mesmo com os outros componentes.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Tentei isso, sem sucesso também amigo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe esse outro exemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

# Funções...

def Cumprimente():
    hello.set("Olá, mundo!")

# Interface...

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Olá Mundo")
gui.geometry("400x400")

btn = Button(gui, text="Cumprimente", command=Cumprimente)
btn.pack()

hello = StringVar()
lbl = Label(gui, textvariable=hello)
lbl.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

O texto do Label não recebe valores diretamente do Python, e por isso você precisa utilizar o objeto "StringVar"...

```
hello = StringVar()
```

Passando em seguida a variável de texto como parâmetro do objeto Label...

```
lbl = Label(gui, textvariable=hello)
```

Desta forma, quando a minha função "Cumprimente" é chamada, não é o Label quem muda, e sim o objeto "hello" (StringVar) através do método "set"...

```
def Cumprimente():
    hello.set("Olá, mundo!")
```

Salve e execute o exemplo para ver a coisa em ação.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sei que este tópico é antigo, mas, pra quem é iniciando que possa cair neste link como eu caí, uma das formas mais simples de alterar o label ao executar um "command" seria o configure do label. Exemplo:

```
# Importando o Tkinter
from tkinter import *

# Importando o Custom Tk com o apelido ctk - Será usado para o Button
import customtkinter as ctk

# Configuração da janela
janela = Tk()
janela.title("Teste de Label")

largura = 450
altura = 250

largura_do_monitor = janela.winfo_screenwidth()
altura_do_monitor = janela.winfo_screenheight()

posx = largura_do_monitor / 2 - largura / 2
posy = altura_do_monitor / 2 - altura / 2
janela.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (largura, altura, posx, posy))


# Função para alterar o texto do Label ao clicar no botão
def clicou():
    texto.configure(text='Você clicou né!?')

# Widget Label
texto = Label(text="", font="arial 14 bold")
texto.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# Widget Button do CTK
botao = ctk.CTkButton(janela, 
                      text="Clica aí!", 
                      command=clicou)
botao.pack(anchor=CENTER, 
           pady=70)


janela.mainloop()
```

---

Neste Exemplo o configure irá trocar o texto do Label ao executar a função "clicou" que está vinculada ao Button "botao".

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ola wag poderia tentar da seguinte forma também:

```
import tkMessageBox

def Open():
text_contents = text.get()
url = str(socket.gethostbyname( text.get() ))

if url != '0.0.0.0':
    webbrowser.open("http://%s" %url)
else:
    #Erro para a label aqui
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("error", "erro a Url que você inseriu não existe")
```

recomendo dar uma olha em como tratar erros seria uma boa.

http://turing.com.br/pydoc/2.7/tutorial/errors.html